# This app is incompatible with all of your devices after uploading apk to production android play store error

Tags: android, google-play

After  uploading apk to production my android app is not being installed.I have try on more then 10 different devices but it gives same error for all device "This app is incompatible with all of your devices."

I have added screen shot for phone,7 inch tablet and 10 inch also but still error persist.
What the problem in upload apk.Please help me in this problem

Thanks in advance.

**EDITED**
Below is my manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.nygci.warangal"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.1" >

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-sdk

    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<permission
    android:name="com.nygci.warangal.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<protected-broadcast android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.nygci.warangal.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony.cdma"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony.gsm"
    android:required="false" />
//some permission for sony mobile
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonymobile.permission.XSSM_PROVIDER" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonymobile.permission.XSSM" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonymobile.permission.ENTERPRISE_API" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sony.smallapp.app.widget.permission.BIND_SMALLAPP_WIDGET_MANAGER" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sony.smallapp.permission.SMALLAPPMANAGER_CONTROL" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sony.smallapp.launcher.permission.ACCESS_DATABASE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sony.smallapp.permission.SMALLAPP" />

<permission
    android:name="com.sonymobile.permission.TASK_SWITCHER_PLUGIN_VIEW"
    android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem" />
```

Comment: Please share your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is due to the permissions you are asking for.  In general tablets don't have telephony, so apps won't show up if there are permissions requesting this.

You additionally have a lot of "Sony" specific permissions, I would guess these might eliminate your phone from showing up on devices that don't support this (ie. anything not Sony).

(Note: I deleted the ones from this list, that didn't look problematic, otherwise, I think any/all of these are likely causing your availability issues).

Decide if you really need the following permissions, and eliminate them if possible:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony.cdma"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony.gsm"
    android:required="false" />
//some permission for sony mobile
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonymobile.permission.XSSM_PROVIDER" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonymobile.permission.XSSM" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonymobile.permission.ENTERPRISE_API" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sony.smallapp.app.widget.permission.BIND_SMALLAPP_WIDGET_MANAGER" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sony.smallapp.permission.SMALLAPPMANAGER_CONTROL" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sony.smallapp.launcher.permission.ACCESS_DATABASE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sony.smallapp.permission.SMALLAPP" />
```

Comment: ok,after removing those permissions i upload new apk in production.